# TextGeometry and PointCloud

Tags: three.js

I want to obtain vertixes for any given text. Text is created via TextGeometry and then PointCloud is instantiated:

```
var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "three.js", {...});
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color:0x8080FF,
            side:THREE.DoubleSide,
        });
textObject = new THREE.PointCloud( textGeo, textMaterial)
```

The effect is following:

[image: PointCloud]

As you can see, the issue is that, points are not uniformely distributed, especially they are missing on straight lines.

Do you guys have any suggestions how to achieve a nicer effect?

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. And I change the .JSON in THREE.FontLoader.load(),then I can see most of the points.

```
fontLoader.load('build/optimer_bold.typeface.json',
    function (font) {
        let fontOptions = {
            font:font,
            size:10
            ......
        }
        .....
    }

);
```

Try the `optimer_bold.typeface.json`.